# WordPress Theme Editor Stylesheet File Editor Error

Tags: php, wordpress

I have wordpress website. I am trying to change css code under Theme Editor> Stylesheet. But when i click on update file button an error occurred.

> Something went wrong. Your change may not have been saved. Please try
>   again. There is also a chance that you may need to manually fix and
>   upload the file over FTP.

Can anyone let me know how do i solve this problem?

Comment: Check the permissions on your file.  Most likely PHP only has read and execute, not write.  And as your working though wordpress your using the PHP user on the system.  I won't even tell you how many times I uploaded files as root, or something else ... lol ... Its actually better, security wise, if PHP cannot overwrite files.  if it's `0655` which is pretty common and not owned by `apache` or sometimes `nobody`---

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I have checked everything. Changed file permission too. But nothing works.

Comment: I actually made a small plugin that adds a custom style sheet, but I was too lazy (lol) to make an editor so I used the same one your using, and what I said above was the issue I had with it.  If it's not that then?  It's kind of a pain to link to it too.

Comment: Have you guys fixed that? I am having the same issue. @Jack

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix